# Can't get my DialogFragment background to be transparent

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I have created a custom DialogFragment like it is described in the developer guide.
Now what I am trying to do sounds simple enough, but I cannot get it to work.
I have defined: `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` in my layout xml which I am loading like this (in my onCreateDialog):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pausedialog, null);
setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.CustomDialog);
```

As you can see I also tried to set a custom style in the DialogFragment which is defined like this:

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item> 
    <item name="android:alwaysDrawnWithCache">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

And I also tried `getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));`
which leads to a null pointer exception.

I am using `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`. Can this be the cause?
Or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try to set style and theme in onCreate method of your dialogFragment class implementation.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         int style=DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE;
         int theme=android.R.style.Theme_Translucent;
         setStyle(style, theme);
    }
```

Or

if you are using Dialog class then you can also set Style and theme on dialog instance.

Comment: what are you getting ?
can you post the screenshot ?

Comment: Please check if you are setting style and theme before setting view to your dialog .Once you set the view it will not change its theme.
Perhaps that may be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. I created a new style:

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And then set this style in my DialogFragment's `onCreate()` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.CustomDialog);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the style I use to totally remove the Dialog`s background.-

```
<style name="Theme.Dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

As for the `Dialog` creation, you're creating a `DialogBuilder` but then you manually inflate a view, I guess that's the problem. Try this instead.-

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.customTheme));
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

**EDIT**

Another approach is extending `AlertDialog`.-

```
public class CustomDialog extends AlertDialog {
    public DialogParent(Context context) {
        super(context, R.style.CustomDialog);
        setContentView(R.layout.pausedialog);

        // More initialization stuff    
    }
}
```

And then 'manually' instantiate it.-

```
AlertDialog dialog = new CustomDialog(getActivity());
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Didnt't work :/. I am loading the style after i am inflating the layout. 
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pausedialog, null);
setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.CustomDialog);

Comment: My bad, didn't notice the inflate part, I guess that may be the problem. Just edited my answer.

Comment: I am inflating the view manually because i need it to find my TextViews: TextView tResume = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tResume);
I want to support API level 8 and above, but there is no "new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.CustomDialog);" supported

Comment: Sorry, bad copypaste :( Just fixed it. As for finding your inner views, you can actually do `dialog.findViewById(R.id.tResume)`

Comment: This will give me a null pointer exception. I am kinda confused of why i am loading a style rather than a layout in the ContextThemeWrapper. I am also asking myself where my layout would be inflated then?

Comment: Mmh maybe the easiest way (at least what works for me), is extend Dialog class and setup style and layout in `onCreate`

Comment: The OP use `DialogFragment` not `Dialog`.