# View outside a Dialogs bounds

Tags: android-layout, android, android-dialog

I want something like this:

[image: playstorereview]

The users profile picture is "popping out" over the dialogs bounds.

I've tried everything: messing with clipping with every possibly combination under the sun, dynamically creating the view after the dialog and adding it to the root content view, using a seperate view and loading that in with Dialog.setCustomTitle(), hacking the Images onDraw() methods and applying all-sorts of bounds/positional hacks --- but no matter what the image always gets clipped and split in half.

I've even gone to the extent of decompiling the Play Store APK and seeing how they did it. Unfortunately the resource files don't give much away and I can't find anything in the Smali.

Can anyone help? Please... :-(

**EDIT**: I'm just specifically talking about the user profile image at the top of the dialog, not the dialog itself.

Comment: Have you tried using an `Activity` with `dialog-theme` yet? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979369/android-activity-as-a-dialog)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

dialog method:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mhp);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
```

mhp.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

result
[image: Result picture]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I wanted to use AlertDialog but the transparency wouldn't work. This did the trick for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20015598/486604

Answer (score 4):

It looks like they are just having an rounded Image inside an ImageView and having a Layout with margin from top which is half of the imagesize,

So, if my imagesize is `100px`, I should use `50dip` to show image centered in all screen

```
 dialog.xml
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dip" 
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" >
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/download" />
```

And then you just have your Dialog with Background Transparent

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                                 new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.show();
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just to improve @MHP's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25361718/3955965), you can also add cardView to make the corner of your dialog rounded.

Something like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/llMainContents"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FAFAFA"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Result would be:
[image]

Comment: Amazing answer. above all solution i test but your answer is Perfect. And working fine. You save my day.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you should make background of your dialog transparent.
For DialogFragment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23729785.
For AlertDialog: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19175448.
Secondly, combine your layouts in a way, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <TextView
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="blablabla"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Where iv1 is header image