# how can i put an image out of the dialog

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

i want to put an image in top of a dialog with half out of the dialog and half inside the dialog as shown in this image
[image: this image]

i try to do it using constraint layout but it shows like these
[image]

can any one help me to know how to make the image look like it out side the dialog as shown in the first image??

here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="450dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="328dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:text="لحجز الخدمة قم بادخال رقم المريض"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:text="رقم المريض : "
    android:textSize="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cancel_text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText_pation_number"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_pation_number"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="204dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/order_button"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.99"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cancel_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="96dp"
    android:text="الغاء"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.264" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/order_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="124dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="160dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_button"
    android:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:text="حجز"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cancel_text"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.844"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText_pation_number"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.723" />
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using your own layout for dialog, you can make these changes below for getting full result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="28dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        android:translationZ="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/box_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/box_view" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/box_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/customer_found_layout_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            tools:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:text="لحجز الخدمة قم بادخال رقم المريض"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:text="رقم المريض : "
                android:textSize="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cancel_text"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText_pation_number"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_pation_number"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="204dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/order_button"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.99"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cancel_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="96dp"
                android:text="الغاء"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.264" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/order_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="124dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="160dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:text="حجز"
                android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cancel_text"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.844"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText_pation_number"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.723" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What i did is removed imageView from it's parent and wrapped in into new parent making sibling of CardView.

I have changed backgrounds and colors, you undo those as required.

Comment: thanks for your help i edit many things in your code but doesn't give me what i want but you give some push froward so i will up-vote your answer and you can see what is the full as i posted up there

Comment: Show me changes so far you have made respect to my answer which i have posted, then it would be easy for follow-up.

Comment: i added android:background="@color/transparent" to parent layout and added android:background="@color/transparent" to image and i make the constraint layout visible and all the layout in fall apart so now i have ti fix it before deliver it to the customer

Answer (score 0):

i found what i was looking forward [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361027/view-outside-a-dialogs-bounds)

i changed my code as [rajasekhar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7725103/rajasekhar) suggested to me

my code went like these

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@color/transparent"
android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="28dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
    android:translationZ="50dp"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/box_view"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/box_view" />

 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/box_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/customer_found_layout_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"

        tools:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
            android:text="لحجز الخدمة قم بادخال رقم المريض"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:text="رقم المريض : "
            android:textSize="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cancel_text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText_pation_number"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_pation_number"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="204dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/order_button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.99"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cancel_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="96dp"
            android:text="الغاء"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.264" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/order_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="124dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="160dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:shadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="حجز"
            android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cancel_text"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.844"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText_pation_number"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.723" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

but these is not been what i want but as [mhp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553815/mhp) said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361027/view-outside-a-dialogs-bounds)
i added one line to my java code

```
 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

and now it;s worked as i wanted